# DynamoDB TTL - when Items are removed

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Does dynanodb has a limitation  taking upto 48 hours to delete expired rows ?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html

Since I want to execute a Lambda when a row is deleted from dynamo db table, so that means my lambda trigger can take upto 48 hours ?

Answer (score 26):

Yes according to the [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html) you sent.

> DynamoDB typically deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration. The exact duration within which an item truly gets deleted after expiration is specific to the nature of the workload and the size of the table. Items that have expired and not been deleted will still show up in reads, queries, and scans.

If you have a Lambda trigger on delete it will happen on delete which could be `within 48 hours of expiration` (according to the link you sent).

Comment: Is it the same SLA for delete item? Meaning explixit delete that I run?

Comment: Manual deletes happen immediately

Answer (score 5):

Commonly takes 24 - 48 hours to be deleted, but keep in mind those items with expired TTL could still appearing in queries and scans. To avoid "phantom reads" you can use a [Filter Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression) to check if the TTL value is greater than current date.

More info in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html).